# nesty panel element inline styling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

the following form is here:

https://help.betterbathrooms.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

I have tried to figure this one out but it seems when I click on enquiry type the nesty-panel element is out of position. Even when I scroll down the panel seems to miove further down.

I have tried to using jQuery to fix the issue:-

```
$("div.nesty-panel").removeAttr("style");
```

this does not seem to be working?

for some reason there are inline style elements being appended to the nesty panel even though in the css there is none related and there is no mention of the element in javascript?

can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Please provide your code in a fiddle

Comment: That's because there **is** CSS applied to it and when you disable them in inspector, the page goes back to normal. The CSS is here https://p3.zdassets.com/hc/themes/1461263/115001094349/style-cc5f2087504cccb7453e5aa91d721237.css?brand_id=2189269&locale=en-us

Answer (score 0):

Your page has below error hence it could be related because .nesty-panel class is defined in that css.

> new:1 Failed to load https://p3.zdassets.com/hc/assets/application-a1fa96afa47eb18d40b332ccf9033704.css: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://help.betterbathrooms.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   new:1 Failed to load https://p3.zdassets.com/hc/themes/1461263/115001094349/style-cc5f2087504cccb7453e5aa91d721237.css?brand_id=2189269&locale=en-us: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://help.betterbathrooms.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   main.js:1 Our embeddable contains third-party, open source software and/or libraries. To view them and their license terms, go to http://goto.zendesk.com/embeddable-legal-notices